# send email using Laravel 5 & Amazon SES

Tags: email, laravel-5, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send an email in Laravel using Amazon SES driver but keep getting this error:

> "local.ERROR: exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message
>   'Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530
>   Authentication required "' in
>   /***/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383"

in mail.php the driver is 'ses', in services I've set up the key, secret and region. Also checked .env to make all the data match, but still getting this error. I know that is not on the Amazon side because we have that very same account sending emails in another script, so I'm sure it's some wrong configuration in Laravel, I just don't know where else to look... help?

Comment: I was able to make it work with PHPMailer in laravel, but im curious about how to use the default methods from laravel...

Comment: ok, first error was to use the amazon smtp endpoint with the API

Comment: Ok, after a lot of digging, I manage to try to check credentials with amazon, but got rejected. Good thing is that in the way to rejection I learn a few things. First what i already mentioned about smtp endpoint, second, the credentials go in the root of the computer, not the project or site (don't get confuse with ~ which is the home of the current user) so the code I used to check this was: `$s3 = new S3Client([
            'profile'   => 'default',
            'version'   => 'latest',
            'region'    => 'eu-west-1' ]); $result = $s3->listBuckets(); var_dump($result);`

Comment: last error says `SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. `

Comment: at the end, the service wasn't active, so that's my manager fault! but i managed to make it work! :P

Answer (score 1):

Have you added all needed configurations?

.env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=**********USERNAME**********
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********PASSWORD**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

At least, such configuration works with Laravel 5.1

Comment: I was missing the encryption... i changed it and now getting error: `local.ERROR: exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 220 but got code "500", with message "500 Error: command not implemented
"' in /***/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383`

Answer (score 0):

Check the config/mail.php

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'ses'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', ''),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', ''),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', ''),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
];
```

Make sure the .env file has the following

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com // hosting site
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your username
MAIL_PASSWORD=your password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Also clear the config cache

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8, AWS 3.178 for aws/aws-sdk-php

.env should look like this

```
#MAIL_MAILER=smtp
#MAIL_HOST=mailhog
#MAIL_PORT=1025
#MAIL_USERNAME=null
#MAIL_PASSWORD=null
#MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
#MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
#MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

MAIL_MAILER=ses
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=yourkey
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yoursecreaccesskey
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-southeast-1
AWS_BUCKET=
```

Notice the first line is not `MAIL_DRIVER=ses` but it should be `MAIL_MAILER=ses`